# Metro UI CSS Framework - Carousel Not Working

Tags: css, frameworks, carousel

I have just started using this Metro UI CSS, but cannot get carousel to work.

The carousel displays only the last slide and nothing else! No animation! Nothing. Even if I click the next and previous buttons, nothing happens! Please help!

My code:

Interfaz Windows 8

```
<body class="metrouicss">           
    <div class="carousel" data-role="carousel" data-param-auto="false" data-param-effect="fade" style="height:300px; width:450px">
        <div class="slides">
            <div class="slide image" id="slide1">
                <img src="imagenes/00384059-000730_catl_500.jpg">
                <div class="description">
                    Description text here...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slide mixed" id="slide2">
                <img src="imagenes/00384059-000730_catl_500.jpg">
                <div class="description">
                    Description text here...
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>

        <span class="control left">‹</span>
        <span class="control right">›</span>     
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Any chance we could see the carousel.js code?

Comment: Try adding a script-reference to jQuery...

Comment: Does anybody have an answer yet ?!

Comment: Have you tried put `class="metro"` in `<body>` tag as required?